# My loop is only displaying the last data value in my view - firebase

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display all the equipment list that i retrieve from the firebase database using angular.foreach but when ever i try to display the retrieved values in my view it only displays the last value. Need help!

**My JS**

```
/*global angular*/
var app = angular.module('sdt', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider.when('/sdt', {
        templateUrl: 'searchdowntime/sdt.html',
        controller: 'sdtCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('sdtCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    'use strict';

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        var data = ref.child("data");
        var list = $firebaseArray(data);

        list.$loaded().then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            angular.forEach ($scope.data , function (d) {
                angular.forEach (d.equipments, function (e) {
                    $scope.allEquipments = e;
                    console.log($scope.allEquipments);
                })
            });
            console.log($scope.data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        });




}]);
```

**My html**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
     <tr>
        <th id="system">System</th>
        <th id="equipment">Equipment</th>
        <th id="date">Date</th>
        <th id="type">Type</th>
     </tr>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="d in allEquipments">
        <td headers = "system">System</td>
        <td headers = "equipment" >{{d}}</td>
        <td headers = "date">date</td>
        <td headers = "type">Standby</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

console log:

[image: console log]

view:

[image: view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you always changing the value of `$scope.allEquipments` for every iteration. You need to push it into an array instead.

```
app.controller('sdtCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    'use strict';

    // Add this line
    $scope.allEquipments = [];
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        var data = ref.child("data");
        var list = $firebaseArray(data);

        list.$loaded().then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            angular.forEach ($scope.data , function (d) {
                angular.forEach (d.equipments, function (e) {
                    // Change this line
                    $scope.allEquipments.push(e);
                    console.log($scope.allEquipments);
                })
            });
            console.log($scope.data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        });
}]);
```

And your `ng-repeat` to

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="d in allEquipments">
    <td headers = "system">System</td>
    <td headers = "equipment" >{{d.equipment}}</td>
    <td headers = "date">date</td>
    <td headers = "type">Standby</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you. <3 <3 <3